# Text replace on unix

Tags: unix

I would like to replace these statement  by the following, on a `Unix` system, does some one know how I can do that ?

```
/www/docs/syndrome.ms.fcm
```

by

```
$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, with [sed](/questions/tagged/sed) :

```
sed -i "s@/www/docs/syndrome.ms.fcm@\$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']@g" $(
    grep -l "/www/docs/syndrome.ms.fcm" *files
)
```

If you don't have the `-i` switch :

```
for f in $(grep -l "/www/docs/syndrome.ms.fcm" *files); do
    sed "s@/www/docs/syndrome.ms.fcm@\$_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']@g" "$f" > newfile &&
    mv newfile "$f"
done
```